# Windows Phone Reserved Folders

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

The folders that you see when you connect your phone to PC using USB, are they same across different languages in which Widnows Phones are distributed?
For instance, if I need to instruct the users of my app to download certain files from my website and put into the SD Card, can I request them to place the files in "SD card" > "Videos" > "my_game_resource.wmv" or will the folder names be different say in a "russian" phone?
I did set my english phone into different languages and obviously the folder names remained the same. But I have heard that it depends on the "build" of the ROM and its base language. Does that mean that a phone with Russian ROM will read these folder names in Russian?
Sorry, but I don't have a phone in other language and the revenues from WP Store are too poor to afford more than what I already have :). Any help to confirm this will be highly appreciated. Also, if they are different, is there a reference list for folder names in different languages that I can refer to?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that this forum does not have good many responses... I was thinking at least this one will get some answers.